# Google analytic shows me wired links for one of my visitors

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website wich is registered with google analytic so I can see the statistics of it The problem is that sometime it shows me this link :

```
website.com/www.bndv521.cf/
```

or:

```
website.com/admin
```

I do not know if this is a hacker trying to hack me or something but I think nobody will try to access my admin for good

Can you help me to know what is this link refers to ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking for a malicious code included on your pages. And yes it's likely that some one is trying to access those pages but it may not execute because it's invalid path. You should consider blocking such ip addresses after checking in logs.

Comment: Do you mean the logs in my web public folder or somewhere in the analytic page in google?

Comment: Yes, check raw access logs depending on your web hosting. Not in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Although trying to reach an admin page seems a suspicious action, in our website we come accross this issue every one in ten thousand requests.

We think that a browser extension or a virus like program tries to change URL or trying to add this keyword to URL. Not for a hacking purpose, but to redirect to their advertisement website.

Very similar issue here: [Weird characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222973/weird-characters-in-url)